# specify nuget package version conditionally

Tags: c#, nuget

Let's say I am working on a Feature  (C# project) that is toggled off, i.e. not ready to be released.

My project depends on a component via nuget, which is also something I maintain.

My feature requires changes to the component, as well as my consuming project.

I need to make intermediate releases, and I prefer not to branch.

In my project, I can toggle the Feature off and ship. Question is : how do I use nuget in a feature toggled project, such that if Feature is off, I use version X of component, and version X+1 when the feature is on.

- I could not find any way of adding conditions to `packages.config`

The only thing I can think of is, use a different feed for non-release environment, but that could lead to other logistical issues.

Edit:

My builds run on a CI server, so I need to be able to script it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the NuGet source then you can use the [Pre-Release functionality](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/prerelease-packages).

Essentially you version control your Nuget packages by suffixing them with `-alpha` or `-beta` and then in Visual Studio you tick the check box for "Include prelease" in you NuGet package feed.

For using a switch on a build server I suggest you look at using MSBuild / MSBuild Community Tasks / MSBuild Extension pack.

You can run a build step using MSBuild that can examine a config file and amend a .nuspec file. I don't have the source to hand as it was a while ago, but it is possible to use xml / msbuild to parse an xml file and apply changes to it. IIRC a big "gotcha" was that you need to specifiy the `.nusepc` namespace

`<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2016/06/nuspec.xsd">`

when you are parsing the nuspec file.It should then be possible to target the `<dependencies>` element and suffix all the dependecies with the pre-release tag.

Comment: Right, but then how do I control "Include prerelease" programatically? I don't build manually, my builds run on CI, so I prefer something that is scriptable. thanks.

Comment: Use command line (as you must be using it for CI) and pass the version through it for each release

Comment: @muhammadwaqas - any tips on how to specify nuget package version via msbuild would be awesome!

Comment: I have been trying to do it , but couldn't find any suitable way. I am using bamboo , so my idea was to increment the version number in the .nuspec file through a powershell script, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-custom-tasks-in-msbuild-to-modify-xml-configuration-fi loosk promising. I have done it in the past using pure xml / msbuild with a .targets file and a .proj file